# ImportError: Couldn't import Django after running " heroku python manage.py migrate" in CMD

Tags: django, heroku

I have a following error after running " heroku python manage.py migrate " in CMD.

```
C:\Users\ky2001\Desktop\my_app>heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python3 manage.py migrate on ⬢ leadersbooks... up, run.6589 (Free)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I have tried
1. removing "`Pipfile`" and run again
2. running "`heroku python manage.py makemigrations`" first
3. changing `python` to `python3`
4. re-deployment of the app
5.(my requirements.txt file, Procfile and Pipdile are in roots directly)

but non of them worked.
and I do have django in my requirements.txt

Please help me if you have any solution..

My codes are as follows.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn personal_portfolio.wsgi --log-file -
```

Pipfile

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"


[packages]



[dev-packages]

pytest = "*"
django = "*"
dj-database-url = "*"
whitenoise = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
twine = "*"
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault(
        "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "personal_portfolio.settings"
    )
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

requirements.txt

```
absl-py==0.7.1
appdirs==1.4.3
arabic-reshaper==2.0.15
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astor==0.7.1
attrdict==2.0.0
attrs==19.1.0
backcall==0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
bleach==3.1.0
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.12.3
chardet==3.0.4
clarifai==2.6.2
click==6.7
cmake==3.15.3
colorama==0.4.1
configparser==3.8.1
cryptography==2.7
cycler==0.10.0
cytoolz==0.9.0.1
DateTime==4.3
decorator==4.0.11
defusedxml==0.5.0
dill==0.3.1.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.7
django-allauth==0.41.0
django-classy-tags==1.0.0
django-cms==3.7.3
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
django-formtools==2.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-js-asset==1.2.2
django-mptt==0.11.0
django-sekizai==1.1.0
django-taggit==1.3.0
django-tinymce==3.0.2
django-treebeard==4.3.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.5.0
easyprocess==0.2.7
emoji==0.5.4
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
eth-abi==1.3.0
eth-account==0.3.0
eth-hash==0.2.0
eth-keyfile==0.5.1
eth-keys==0.2.1
eth-rlp==0.1.2
eth-typing==2.1.0
eth-utils==1.4.1
ez-setup==0.9
face-recognition==1.2.3
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
ffmpeg-python==0.2.0
filetype==1.0.5
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-MySQL==1.4.0
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
future==0.17.1
gast==0.2.2
google-speech==1.1.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
googletrans==2.4.0
grpcio==1.19.0
gTTS==2.0.4
gTTS-token==1.1.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
h5py==2.9.0
hexbytes==0.1.0
html5lib==1.0.1
huepy==0.9.8.1
idna==2.8
image==1.5.27
imageio==2.1.2
instabot==0.60.0
instagram-private-api==1.6.0.0
instagram-private-api-extensions==0.3.8
InstagramAPI==1.0.2
instapy-cli==0.0.12
ipykernel==5.1.0
ipython==7.4.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.4.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jaconv==0.2.4
jdcal==1.4.1
jedi==0.13.3
Jinja2==2.10
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.2.4
jupyter-console==6.0.0
jupyter-contrib-core==0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.1
jupyter-core==4.4.0
jupyter-highlight-selected-word==0.2.0
jupyter-latex-envs==1.4.6
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator==0.4.1
Keras==2.2.4
Keras-Applications==1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing==1.0.9
kiwisolver==1.0.1
klepto==0.1.8
kytea==0.1.5
lru-dict==1.1.6
lxml==4.3.2
Markdown==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.0.3
MeaningCloud-python==1.1.1
mistune==0.8.4
mock==2.0.0
moviepy==0.2.3.2
mysql==0.0.2
mysql-connector==2.2.9
mysql-connector-python==8.0.15
mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1
nbconvert==5.4.1
nbformat==4.4.0
notebook==5.7.6
numpy==1.16.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-python==4.0.0.21
openpyxl==2.6.2
pandas==0.24.2
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parsimonious==0.8.1
parso==0.3.4
passlib==1.7.1
pbr==5.1.3
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==6.2.0
pipenv==2018.11.26
plyer==1.4.2
pox==0.2.7
prometheus-client==0.6.0
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
protobuf==3.7.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
py-solc==3.2.0
pycparser==2.19
pycryptodome==3.8.1
pyee==6.0.0
Pygments==2.3.1
pykakasi==1.2
PyMySQL==0.9.3
PyNLPIR==0.6.0
pyOpenSSL==19.0.0
pyparsing==2.3.1
pyrsistent==0.14.11
PySocks==1.7.1
python-bidi==0.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-telegram-bot==12.1.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
PyYAML==5.1
pyzmq==18.0.1
qtconsole==4.4.3
regex==2019.8.19
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
requests-toolbelt==0.7.0
responses==0.10.6
rlp==1.1.0
schedule==0.6.0
scikit-learn==0.20.3
scipy==1.2.1
seaborn==0.9.0
selenium==3.141.0
semantic-version==2.6.0
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.8
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.1
testpath==0.4.2
TFANN==1.0.1
toolz==0.9.0
tornado==6.0.1
tqdm==4.11.2
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==16.4.3
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
wcwidth==0.1.7
web-cache==1.1.0
web3==4.9.1
webdriverdownloader==1.0.0.1
webencodings==0.5.1
websockets==6.0
Werkzeug==0.15.1
whitenoise==5.1.0
widgetsnbextension==3.4.2
WTForms==2.2.1
xlrd==1.2.0
you-get==0.4.1423
zope.interface==5.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not create a Procfile.
I thought I did by running `web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi` but I needed to create a file which contains this code.